# Does vmware clarity datagrid has an option to use tree data?

Tags: vmware-clarity

Does datagrid component has a tree data model? (for example, like in ag-grid: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tree-data/#example-org-hierarchy) ?

Answer (score 1):

The datagrid does not have a tree data model, but there is a tree view component for that kind of data structure. You would have to work out the styling for each of the items though.

https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.12/tree-view